# list index out of range: iteration of two lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indexing, range

I'm having difficulty with printing text from one list, and playing the soundbyte for each list after it prints. However if there is a second sentence, but no second soundbyte, I get list index out of range.

What do I do if the second list has no second item? etc...

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.mixer.init()
a="first sentence..."
b="second sentence..."
sentList=[]
sentList.append(a)
sentList.append(b)
sound1= pygame.mixer.Sound('lose1.ogg')
soundList=[]
soundList.append(sound1)
chan1=""
for i in range (len(sentList)):
    print sentList[i]
    chan1= soundList[i].play()
    while chan1.get_busy():
        z=0
```

Comment: use try and except https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 1):

you can use `zip`, a simple example:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [4,5]
>>> for i,j in zip(a, b):
        print i, j
1 4
2 5
```

so your code can be like this:

```
for i,j in zip(sentList, soundList):
    print i
    chan1 = j.play()
    while chan1.get_busy():
        z = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok -

`sentList` has a length of 2 (you append it twice).  `soundList` has a length 1.  In your for loop, you are trying to access the second element of `soundList`, which does't exist.  That is why an error is thrown.  To solve this, you can enclose `chan1= soundList[i].play()` in a try catch to look like this.

```
try:
    chan1= soundList[i].play()
except:
    print("error")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put a condition in to see if the item exists in the list:

```
if len(soundList) > i:
   chan1= soundList[i].play()
   while chan1.get_busy():
      z=0
```

or you use a `try` block:

```
try:
   chan1= soundList[i].play()
   while chan1.get_busy():
      z=0
except IndexError:
    print 'ListIndex does not exist'
```